# featured post as div background

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, css, html

Ok I didn't find an answer yet.. because my code is different.. I want to set the featured image as the div's background but I don't know how to do that.. html, php and css collide in one line..
This is the div..

```
echo '<div id = "circ"><ul><li><a href = "';
the_permalink(); echo '">'; '</a></li></ul></div>'; ?>
```

and this is the code I want..

```
 $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src ( get_post_thumbnail_id('thumbnail'));


<div id = "circ" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;">test</div>
```

I could have inserted it in one line like this

```
echo '<div id = "circ" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0];><ul><li><a href = "';
the_permalink(); echo '">'; '</a></li></ul></div>';
```

but then they all collide which I don't know  the workaround for it..

Comment: What do you mean by "collide in one line"? Also, this is looking like a pure PHP problem to me.

Comment: for the function `get_post_thumbnail_id`, the argument should be `post_id` (`interger`), but you have given size attribute `thumbnail`. you can completely remove `'thumbnail'` from the function, it should work then

Answer (score 0):

You're code is not working as you have an echo within an echo, try this code (not tested)

```
<?php
echo '<div id = "circ" style="background: url('.$src[0].'><ul><li><a href = "'.the_permalink().'</a></li></ul></div>';
?>
```

If you're echo'ing something and then you want to add php within that echo you need to break the echo by adding '. $variable .'